# Jinja2 inheritance won't work

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to use inheritance in jinja2 on google app engine. But I haven't managed to do it so far. Could you please point me to what I am doing wrong?

Here is my `base.html`:

```
{{text}}
{% block title %}
Failure
{% endblock %}
```

this template is extended by the `title.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
World!!
{% endblock %}
```

Both templates are in the same directory `/templates/wiki`.

This is how I load templates and render `base.html`:

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../templates/wiki')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    templ = jinja_env.get_template('base.html')
    self.response.out.write(templ.render(text = 'Hello,'))
```

The supposed output is

> Hello, World!!!

but I can get just:

> Hello, Failure

Jinja2 version is 2.6.

Comment: Are you always loading the 'base.html' template (tmpl = jinja_env.get_template('base.html)?

Comment: @Nicoretti I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to render title.html instead of base.html.